# CATransition for segue animation (pre iOS 7 style)

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, segue

I have a custom segue, trying to replicate the push/pop segues of the pre iOS 7 style:

**viewControllers animating SIDE-BY-SIDE, with NO darkening.** (Is it really that hard!)

The code below works, except:

- the exiting page becomes dark on exit
- the entering page is dark on entering (gradually becomes normal as it moves into position)

These images illustrate the problem:

[image] and then...  [image]

**Is there a way to stop this darkening effect?** I would be really grateful for some help.

```
-(void)perform
{
    UIViewController *source = self.sourceViewController;
    UIWindow *window = source.view.window;

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    [transition setDuration:2.0];
    [transition setDelegate:self];
    [transition setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear]];
    [transition setType:@"push"];
    [transition setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];

    [window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
    [window setRootViewController:self.destinationViewController];
}
```

Comment: I have resorted to animating viewController views to create my segue (not as tidy), instead of using the CATransition. However, I will leave this question open, in case it helps anyone else.

Comment: you get solution or not?

Comment: I did not find a super easy solution unfortunately. I had resort to animating viewController views. (It would be nice if Apple would create an option to remove this unnecessary shading.)

Answer (score 1):

These 2 functions work fine for me, although the code is pretty similar to yours, I hope it helps.

```
+(void) modalRight:(UIViewController*)vc destvc:(UIViewController*)viewCtrl{
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.3;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
    [vc.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
    [vc presentModalViewController:viewCtrl animated:NO];
}

+(void) modalLeft:(UIViewController*)vc{
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.3;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
    [vc.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
    [vc dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Comment: That is very similar to what I am using, but unfortunately, in iOS 7, it is darkening the viewControllers, on the their entry / exit. It is very annoying.